# Httpd.service aint working for Splunk in my pc(Fedora Linux 39 Workstation Edition) and i can't get to the Splunk web interface?

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver

**Httpd is enabled and running fine**

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-02-09 21:07:44 AEST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
   Main PID: 37474 (httpd)
     Status: "Started, listening on: port 80"
      Tasks: 177 (limit: 18945)
     Memory: 15.0M
        CPU: 160ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
             ├─37474 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37475 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37476 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─37477 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             └─37478 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Feb 09 21:07:44 fedora systemd[1]: Starting httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 09 21:07:44 fedora (httpd)[37474]: httpd.service: Referenced but unset environment variable evaluates to an empty string: OPTIONS
Feb 09 21:07:44 fedora httpd[37474]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::7fac>
Feb 09 21:07:44 fedora httpd[37474]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
Feb 09 21:07:44 fedora systemd[1]: Started httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**Splunk Installed and running well**

```
Splunk $sudo /opt/splunk/bin/splunk start

Splunk> Australian for grep.

Checking prerequisites...
    Checking mgmt port [8089]: open
    Checking configuration... Done.
    Checking critical directories...    Done
    Checking indexes...
        Validated: _configtracker _metrics _metrics_rollup _thefishbucket web
    Done
    Checking filesystem compatibility...  Done
    Checking conf files for problems...
            Bad regex value: '(::)?...', of param: props.conf / [(::)?...]; why: this regex is likely to apply to all data and may break summary indexing, among other Splunk features.
        One or more regexes in your configuration are not valid. For details, please see btool.log or directly above.
    Done
    Checking default conf files for edits...
    Validating installed files against hashes from '/opt/splunk/splunk-9.1.3-d95b3299fa65-linux-2.6-x86_64-manifest'
    All installed files intact.
    Done
All preliminary checks passed.

Starting splunk server daemon (splunkd)...  
Done
                                                           **[  OK  ]
STATUS**

Splunk $sudo /opt/splunk/bin/splunk status
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
splunkd is running (PID: 38455).
splunk helpers are running (PIDs: 38457 38590 38651).
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
Splunk $
```

[app WEB interface response]

any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: The Splunk web interface seems to be its own web server so I am not sure if Apache is involved at all.  It looks like default Splunk web runs on port 8000 of `localhost`.  What address and port is Splunk currently running on and what happens when you try to connect to it?